# Counting highlighted cells in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, indexing, highlight, conditional-formatting, countif

Is it possible to count by highlighted cells in Google Sheets?
I have conditional formatting designed to highlight the cell if it is the first time a value appears in Column A of my sheet so would it be possible to count these highlighted cells to show the number of highlighted cells?

I have come up with a fix by using another row which would in essence use the same Index formula `=INDEX(COUNTIFS(B:B,B6,ROW(B:B), ">="&ROW(B6)))=1` I have for the conditional formatting but to show TRUE/FALSE values which can then be counted using COUNTIF but I'd prefer not to add another column if it's possible to count the colours

Edit: Based on responses, I thought I would update with exactly what I require using a test sheet as an example - test sheet can be found at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gAzB-8SX1RnVG26SxgQ5GF2058swl4bQFSq8wSBHjQo/edit?usp=sharing

What I am looking to do is to count the amount of cells in Column B of the Haulage sheet which are highlighted in yellow with red text. The result of this will show in cell `P2` of the Stats sheet. However, this result should also be impacted by only showing the count for results that show in the Date Filter sheet (this sheet is controlled by changing the dates in C1 and C2 of the Stats sheet).

So to give you an indicator of the outcome that should occur - if the date range is 18/05/23 - 18/05/23 the result should be 12. If it is 19/05/23-19/05/23 the result should be 2. And if the range is 18/05/23 - 19/05/23 the result should be 14.

Comment: In that case, for example, is using Google Apps Script included in your expected direction?

Comment: @Tanaike can you recall a solution that does NOT use a script as a answer?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `but I'd prefer not to add another column if it's possible to count the colours` in your question, if you want to directly retrieve the count of the cells including the specific font color, I thought that Google Apps Script might be useful. But, if using a script is not included in your expected result, I apologize.

Comment: To help you get a more accurate answer, it would be beneficial if you could provide a minimal, reproducible example, such as a dummy sheet, that demonstrates the issue you're facing along with your desired result. This would allow the community to better understand your problem and provide targeted solutions. Including a reproducible example will greatly increase your chances of receiving a helpful response.

Comment: @Tanaike I have updated my original question above with further detail

Comment: @George I have updated my original question above with further detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try:

```
=counta(ifna(filter(Haulage!B2:B,map(Haulage!B2:B,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,countif(Haulage!B2:B,Σ)-countif(Haulage!B2:Σ,Σ)+1)))=1,isbetween(Haulage!A2:A,Stats!C1,Stats!C2))))
```

[image]

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to use this for thanking but I have to in this case. Thanks so much @rockinfreakshow - I shall spend my Sunday reading up on "lambda" as that is a function I have not come across before